# TypeError: object of type 'Future' has no len()

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, jupyter-notebook

I have written the following code in `python` `jupyterlite notebook` using `Pyolite` kernel:

```
min_length = 2
name = input("Please enter your name:")

print(name)

while not(len(name) >= min_length and name.isprintable() and name.isalpha()):
    name = input("Please enter your name:")

print("Hello {0}".format(name))
```

Upon executing the above code, I am getting below error:

```
<Future pending>
TypeError: object of type 'Future' has no len()
```

I have not redefined input to be something else anywhere `earlier in the jupyter notebook.`

*More detailed error message:*

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <module>
      6 name = input("Please enter your name:")
      8 print(name)
---> 10 while not(len(name) >= min_length and name.isprintable() and name.isalpha()):
     11     name = input("Please enter your name:")
     13 print("Hello {0}".format(name))

TypeError: object of type 'Future' has no len()
```

Comment: That looks like a bug in Pyolite, particularly in the implementation of the `input` function. Your code is perfectly valid Python syntax.

Comment: I agree with @larsks.  My guess is they implemented input with asyncio and are returning the future rather than the result.

Comment: This issue, along with several other current pain points with jupyterlite/pyolite, is mentioned [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/codes-on-https-jupyter-org-try-jupyter-lab-not-working-properly-anymore/13374/2?u=fomightez). The solution proposed [here](https://github.com/jupyterlite/jupyterlite/issues/275) of adding `await` in front of `input` eliminates the note about 'Future' showing up in the provided code, but even changing them all doesn't make it quite run as well as in a real python kernel. This realm of issues is currently much under development and so things could change fast.

Comment: Actually, it appears adding `await` isn't fixing it for JupyterLab using pyolite (or pyodide) now either. (When I try that, I see `JsException: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'sendInputRequest')` Sorry this cutting-edge stuff still has several issues developers are working out. For now, I suggest using a full python kernel using the links [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/codes-on-https-jupyter-org-try-jupyter-lab-not-working-properly-anymore/13374/4?u=fomightez) to get to your favorite interface.