# How can I get file access in JupyterLab running over the web, which is giving me many errors?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

***Update: I conclude from discussions with others that this is a genuine bug; the web versions of JupyterLab do not currently allow you to access files.***

When I run JupyterLab over the web, e.g. from Jupyter.org/try, I have several difficulties with files. I think something got corrupted -- how can I get a normal JupyterLab environment? Here are some of the problems:

**1) I can not access files from my machine.** The command `os.chdir("C:")` gives the error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 44] No such file or directory: 'C:'
```

**2) I can not access files from the web.** First the command `import pandas as pd` gives the error

```
Could not import the lzma module. Your installed Python is incomplete
```

Then the command `pd.read_csv("https://data.nasa.gov/api/views/7qz6-zrqt/rows.csv")`
(which reads a readily accessible csv file) gives the error

```
URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
```

**3) I can not access the files that I upload into the folders visible at left of the screen.** The command `pwd` returns `'/home/pyodide'` but no amount of moving around from that directory seems to get me to a directory with the files I uploaded or the notebooks I created.

**4) I can not delete some of the files visible in the folders at the left of the screen.** E.g.: I don't remember uploading or modifying the file "Lorenz.ipynb". I try to delete it, and I press "Delete" at this screen, but the file remains.

[image]

I also have JupyterLab installed directly on my machine, where it runs without these problems -- but I am trying to convince people that JupyterLab by web is an easy way of getting into Python, and these errors are preventing that. How can I get JupyterLab working normally over the web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I (and others) didn't see your question earlier. I'm going to largely refer you to where similar things are discussed more recently as this is a very rapidly developing niche.
The short answer is I would suggest not yet encouraging those just get getting into Python to use JupyterLite, which is what you are referring to when you say, "When I run JupyterLab over the web, e.g. from Jupyter.org/try,"[at this time]. You'll note that there and at the [JupyterLite site  itself](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) it status is stated as "experimental", "cutting-edge", "unofficial", etc.

> How can I get JupyterLab working normally over the web?

Go to [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/jupyterlab#jupyterlab--binder) and click `launch binder`. This will give you a temporary session that will time out after ten minutes inactivity on a remote linux-based machine. The Jupyter in use there is full Python-backed. You can upload files by dragging them in the file navigator and you can download new or modified files from the remote machine back to your system. I go more into using it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71971762/8508004). Make sure you note there is a safety net for notebooks even if the session times out.

At this time you'll have a better experience directing folks to MyBinder-served sites with full Python kernels on actual remote machines to address your desire "to convince people that JupyterLab by web is an easy way of getting into Python".

---

If you want to keep using JupyterLite some, please check out the caveats referring to some of the issues you encountered (and more) at the following places:

- [Where files really are in JupyterLite running on your machine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72063769/8508004)
- [FileNotFoundError in JupyterLab (https://jupyter.org/try-jupyter/lab/)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71935110/8508004)
- [pyolite kernel in JupyterLite cannot see file numpy saved](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/problem-with-loading-text-files-jupyterlab-in-python/13866/6?u=fomightez)
- [similar Stackoverflow question and related discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72101606/8508004)
- [more on hurdles at this time for file access for files already in JupyterLite](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/read-files-from-jupyteronline-not-found/14014/2?u=fomightez)
- how `input()` doesn't work covered [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/codes-on-https-jupyter-org-try-jupyter-lab-not-working-properly-anymore/13374/2?u=fomightez) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71106700/8508004)
- [some other pain points of JupyterLite use at this time](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/codes-on-https-jupyter-org-try-jupyter-lab-not-working-properly-anymore/13374/3?u=fomightez)

UPDATE: Everything above referenced the pyolite kernel that was driving JupyterLite at the time. A new kernel compatible with JupyterLite, xeus-python, was [announced](https://twitter.com/martinRenou/status/1541812931654041600). That one enables `time.sleep()` to work in a notebook, more like a typical Python kernel.

Comment: Thanks — I am glad to know that these issues are known and being addressed. In the end I provided detailed instructions for using Idle or JupyterLab locally (including terminal commands for installing packages with pip), and now that I have those, I think I’ll keep using them. If and when they break down I will explore JupyterLite with binder more thoroughly!

Comment: Just to be clear. I meant using a Jupyter environment on a remote computer via MyBinder as **opposed** to JupyterLite.  Two very different alternatives. (You use of *with* was my concern.) MyBinder launched instances (not involving JupyterLite) will be much closer to what you are used to for now. You just have to make them clear it is remote and temporary.

Comment: I was just encountering the "unknown url type https" issue. Is that tracked / explained somewhere?

Comment: Isn't that [described and tracked here](https://github.com/jupyterlite/jupyterlite/issues/744#issue-1313914689)?