# Is JupyterLab on https://try.jupyter.org/ persistent / where does it store your notebooks?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I would like to perform a small, one-day-long coding workshop with some kids and teenagers.

For this, I am looking for a publicly hosted JupyterLab system that we can use for free to write some small Python scripts. One requirement is that we can upload a `.csv` file to this system.

I stumbled across https://try.jupyter.org/ which provides [free JupyterLab instances](https://jupyter.org/try-jupyter/lab/) to use.

**My question:** Does anybody have experience how long scripts stay "uploaded" there? Is the lab regularly reset, or does it store the scripts somewhere locally (in the browser cache, etc.)? We would shut down the PCs to go for lunch and the files should be accessible in the lab again once we restart the PCs.

I know we can download and store the notebooks offline (which we will do, just to make sure) and reupload them if we need, but it would still be nice to know about the persistency of the "Try" service.

Comment: I have tried it before, and have had no problems coming back in an hour or two with it still being there.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not tech support, nor a discussion forum. If you want to know the details of how someone else's website is intended to work, you should check documentation on the site, or ask their support. If you want to know others' experiences with the site in practice, please try Reddit or Quora.

Comment: Try jupyter is hosted by mybinder.org. Currently a notebook server will be terminated (and the storage deleted) after 10 minutes of inactivity. See https://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/about/user-guidelines.html. Check out the mybinder docs - they do have support specifically for teachers.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado: I came back to my session on https://jupyter.org/try-jupyter/lab/ from 20 minutes ago and all files were still there. But thanks for the hint, I will also have a look at [Teaching and Learning with Jupyter](https://jupyter4edu.github.io/jupyter-edu-book/index.html)

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72063769/8508004). This discussion would probably be best posted at the [Jupyter Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/), per Karl's concerns. @MichaelDelgado The current main offerings aren't hosted on MyBinder now. To save money JupyterLite is being used, as the 'Experimental' warning says. These don't time out because they are actually running on the user's machine in the browser using web assembly. MyBinder.org is still available and serving full-Python backer kernels from remote virtual machines.

Comment: Long story, short when using JupyterLite currently, **keep copies of your notebooks and files that are in the JupyterLite session to an actual location on your local drive**. You cannot just navigate in your system's UI to the file that you are currently working on in JupyterLite.

Comment: @MarkusWeninger See [Sample Binder Repositories](https://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/sample_repos.html) for links to those clearly **temporary, not persistent** launches along the lines of what Michael Delgado is suggesting. You have to advise learners to think of that as a remote system and download anything useful generated to local drive.  [There is a safety net](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyterlab-browser-crashed-where-are-my-files/12692/4?u=fomightez) for notebooks.

Answer (score -1):

The [JupyterLite](https://jupyter.org/try-jupyter/lab/) site stores its notebooks in your browser's Local Storage. As such, it will be persistent forever, unless you manually delete your storage. If you go to another browser or another machine, you won't see your notebooks. You can save/export/download those files to your disk as *.ipynb files, and later upload them back if you wish. These notebooks run as WebAssembly Python in your browser. So it's your machine's CPU that executes your notebooks. If you want to use someone else machine (e.g. a notebook service), then they will likely charge you for the privilege - eventually.

> As proof that is is local storage, I opened the https://jupyter.org/try-jupyter/lab/ in Firefox (for example), created a notebook (named "d2f.ipynb") and then opened dev tools (F12) to see [THIS SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5d1b.png)

Otherwise, you can have your students install Python on their laptops (if their machines do not already have it there) and then have them run "pip install jupyter" (among other libraries you might want) and then "jupyter notebook" on the command line. Then your students can run all their notebooks locally and save them. This is what I do with my students.

As for uploading CSV files (e.g. to use with pandas) you can post those on Github, then use a URL to get your CSV files from the web. Else you can just drag-and-drop them into the web site: https://jupyter.org/try-jupyter/lab/ and they will be persistent into your local storage.

Comment: Your post should perhaps mention JupyterLite as that is the technology being currently used at the 'Try Jupyter; site. Because it is JupyterLite [this answer to 'Where is JupyterLite notebook located locally on Windows?'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72063769/8508004) is pertinent to how it works.

Comment: "... in your browser's Local Storage. As such, it will be persistent forever, ..." I worry that for novice users this doesn't adequately acknowledge the lack of convenient direct accessibility to this storage and the relative instability compared to typical storage on a local drive. I advise those using current WASM solutions to think of it as a virtual remote machine and make regular copies & store them in the local storage as they do typical files created by software. Novices are not familiar with using development tools in a browser to access files on their machine.