# I can't install pipelite and pyodide

Tags: python, module

I have been trying to use the "import pipelite" command on my jupyterlab but it keeps giving me "Module not found" error, even after trying to install it no avail. I experienced this same problem with the "pyodide" module.

I tried installing the pipelite module but if came up with an error saying
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pipelite (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pipelite

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: You need to add more details. `piplite` is for JupyterLite and not JupyterLab. And it should be all set up where you access JupyterLite if things are working right. Plus you don't need to explicitly use it now. To keep things consistent between JupyterLite and JupyterLab in the modern Jupyter ecosystem, you can now use `%pip install` in JupyterLite and what actually gets used behind-the-scenes, `piplite`/`micropip`, is handled properly. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75921064/8508004) for an answer that updates the outdated comments I had about `piplite` below the original post.

Comment: @MarceloPaco Python 3.10.9

Comment: @Wayne, Owh... Unfortunately the demo video (data analytics using python) used the "piplite" module on Jupyterlab and it worked. You see, we have a jupyterlab notebook which has all the codes written down to be run on jupyterlab, so that's what I am also trying to do but the error of module not found keeps popping up

Comment: I asked for more details and you still aren't saying where you are running this? JupyterLite uses the Pyodide kernel and so works with piplite and related tech. Just normal JupyterLab with a typical Python, kernel isn't going to work . It is probably okay the video uses piplite but it is outdated and unnecessary. Also it doesn't matter if you have a notebook with the codes written down. If you aren't running it in the right environment, it isn't going to work. You are still better off changing the code to use `%pip install` because that should allow it to work in a typical Python kernel and...

Comment: <continued> a pyodide kernel. JupyterLite is very experimental and changing fast. It is best to avoid its use unless you know what you are doing. Back to details, if you are going to mention courses and videos, then share links when mentioning those. Not just text mentions. If this is a video shared by a course or a person contact them for where to run it. "my jupyterlab" in the first sentence of your post relays very little information. By contrast, I suggest you go to https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ , click 'Lab' in the upper left & then when it starts up drag your notebook...

Comment: <continued> into the panel on the left and then open and run your notebook. Does it work now? If it runs and you change anything make sure you download it back into your computer's normal directory system. Where you dragged it into JupyterLite isn't accessible to your local drive. You can think of it as 'remote' computer. In this case it is buried inside your browser running in web assembly but thinking of it as 'remote' helps you understand you cannot interact with it like if you were using JupyterLab installed via Anaconda on your local machine.

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).