# "Future Pending": Why can't I execute user input in JupyterLab?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, user-input, jupyter-lab

When I try to execute an  `input()` function to generate user input in JupyterLab, it always gives me back the following statement: "Future exception was never retrieved."

For example:

```
number = input("enter a number: ")
print(number)
```

I got back:

> Future exception was never retrieved
> future: <Future finished exception=JsException(TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'sendInputRequest'))>  >Future pending>

I have already tried to restart everything as well as I have tried to use `raw_input()` instead.

I am using the **pyolite** Kernel. The css-loader is Version v5.2.7

Answer (score 1):

This is been answered in my comment in a poorly worded question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71106700/8508004). (The language of that question doesn't address at the underlying issue; OP's question here clearly does get to the heart of the issue.)

You should be able to add `await` as described [here](https://github.com/jupyterlite/jupyterlite/issues/275). It is one of the many issues with JupyterLite/pyolite, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/codes-on-https-jupyter-org-try-jupyter-lab-not-working-properly-anymore/13374/2?u=fomightez) and [the bottom section here listing several current issues encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72130198/8508004) to illustrate how experimental JupyterLite/pyolite is. Unless you absolutely need this to run inside the browser on the client machine using web assembly, at the time you'd probably have a better experience using a typical Python kernel via temporary sessions served in the user's browser backed on remote machines provided my the MyBinder service.

UPDATE: A new kernel compatible with JupyterLite, xeus-python, was [announced](https://twitter.com/martinRenou/status/1541812931654041600). That one works with `time.sleep()`.