# Function Input cell not appearing Jupyter Notebook

Tags: input, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to execute the input function, but the cell to enter information does not appear. What is this about? I am using JupyterLite online. I can't install programs on my computer so I use the web version

[image]

Comment: @jonsca . Those particular ones aren't duplicates. JupyterLite is only about a year old and so what you referenced is unrelated. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72782143/8508004) is a duplicate involving Jupyterlite backed by pyolite kernel.

Comment: Sadly even the solution of putting `await` in front of `input()` isn't working right now.

Comment: For now I suggest the OP use a full python kernel **in a web session of Jupyter** using the links [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/codes-on-https-jupyter-org-try-jupyter-lab-not-working-properly-anymore/13374/4?u=fomightez) to get to your favorite interface. It is backed by the MyBinder service which used to be what the TryJupyter links automatically used. Now they use JupyterLite to just give people a sense of the interface differences and take computational load off MyBinder. However, if you need a kernel backed by Python, use of MyBinder-backed resources is still encouraged.

Comment: @Wayne Thanks for clarifying. Glad I didn't vote to close.  Removed!