# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Future' and 'int' while running code on JupyterLite

Tags: python-3.x

[image: Received error on converting min_1 variable to int(min_1) in line 6]

I have started off with learning python with the help of resources available on the internet and Think Python book by Allen B.Downey. I encountered a question which mentioned conversion of minutes to seconds. However, I am facing an error w.r.t. type of the variable min_1.

I tried converting the variable to int as well which is giving different error. Please guide!

Comment: Please post code as text, not an image of text.

Comment: Last I knew, you cannot use `input()` in JupyterLite, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72789531/8508004). Unless you absolutely need this to run inside the browser on the client machine using web assembly, at the time you'd probably have a better experience using a typical Python kernel via temporary sessions served in the user's browser backed on remote machines provided my the MyBinder service. [Session where `input()` will work](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/binder-examples/requirements/HEAD).

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the outcome of [`input`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp) is a string. Therefore please try:

```
min_1 = int(input("How many minutes?"))
```

And then

```
min_to_sec = min_1 * 60
```

Should work correctly

Answer (score 0):

Return type of `input()` is `string`, which needs to be type casted to `int`, or `float` as per your input.

The code below works fine.

```
min_1 = int(input("How many minutes"))
sec = int(input("How many seconds"))

min_to_sec = min_1 * 60
total_time = min_to_sec + sec

print("Total time: ", total_time)
```